# Questions about traversing, inserting, and deleting nodes

Tags: java, nodes

Just started learning nodes and I have a few questions. Let's say I have a node class that looks like this:

```
    private E number;
    private Node next;
    /**
     *  Constructor
     */
    Node(E e){
       number = e;
       next = null;
    }
```

and I have a series of linked nodes with the starting node named first like so:

first->(1)->(2)->(3)->(5)->(6)

Assuming the list is not empty, to traverse the list, I would do something like so:

```
Node curr = first;
while(curr != null){
    System.out.print(curr);
    curr = curr.next;
}
```

I understand that you cannot traverse a link list like this backwards, so does this mean that whenever I call curr.next the previous elements are just lost?

I was also wondering if first, my original list, will ever be affected by a temporary node list like curr? For example, if I was to insert or delete a node on the list with codes similar to these:

Insert:

```
Node curr = first;
Node newNode = new Node(4);
while(curr != null){
    if(curr.number == 3){
        newNode.next = curr.next;
        curr.next = newNode;
    }
    curr = curr.next;
}
```

Delete:

```
Node curr = first;
Node parent = first;
while(curr != null){
    if(curr.number == 3){
        parent.next = curr.next;
    }
    parent = curr;
    curr = curr.next;
}
```

Would the above code modify first or would I have to set `first = curr;` after the insertion or deletion for the changes take place? If they do modify first, how come `curr = curr.next;` doesn't modify first? What if I wanted to return the deleted node? Would I just do something like `curr.next = null;` and then `return curr;`?

Answer (score 0):

> does this mean that whenever I call curr.next the previous elements are just lost?

As you traversed down the list, you never modified `first` and you never modified the `next` link of any `Node`.  So no node is ever really lost.  Previously visited nodes just become a bit less convenient to access because you don't have a "handle" on them, but you could always find them again by starting back at the head of the list (`first`) and following the `next` links.

> I was also wondering if first, my original list, will ever be affected by a temporary node list like curr?

The variable `first` will never be affected by anything other than an assignment statement having `first` on the left-hand side of the `=`.  On the other hand, the list to which `first` refers might change quite dramatically or be completely unaffected, depending on what you are using `curr` for, but `first` itself can only be affected by assigning a new value to `first`.

> Would the above code modify first or would I have to set first = curr;

The insert and delete code, as given, never modifies `first`. But it *should*, if it is going to be able to handle inserting a new node before the current first node, or deleting the current first node.  Maybe not with `first = curr` specifically, but `first` will definitely need to be updated to reflect a new head of the list.  I leave that, as the textbooks say, "as a exercise for the reader".

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I got it. `first` will change if anything referencing it is modified; otherwise, I would have to update it for the changes to occur.